# How to get vaules from form-fields

Tags: javascript, forms, select, calculator

I'm trying to make a simple calculator with a javascript at the bottom wich calculates the price based on some "values" choosen from a form.

```
<form name="order" method="post" onsubmit="return validering()" action="confirm.php">
<select name="travelers">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2" selected>2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
</form>
```

and I want a script to fetch this value to make calculations:

```
<script>
var travel = getValue(getField("travelers"));
var price_each = 300;

var calc_1 = travel * price_each;
var bonus = utregn_1 * 0.8;

document.write("<p>Calculations</p>");
document.write("Number of travelers: " + travel + "<br>");
document.write("Price each : " + price_each + "<br>");
document.write("Your Price: " + calc_1 + "<br>");

        if (document.getElementById('rabatt').checked) {
            document.write("Your Price: " + bonus);
        }
</script>
```

I'm unable to make the script fetch these values, anyone know whats the matter with my script :)?

In advance, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the `ID` attribute of the `select` Element in `HTML Page` to get the Value from `JavaScript`

Try This:

**HTML:**

```
<select name="travelers" id="travelers">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2" selected>2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var ElementValue=document.getElementById('travelers').value;
```

Comment: multiple discospinns! that worked :D thank you a bunch mate^^

Comment: Hehe, sorry the delay, you just solved it to fast ;P

Answer (score 1):

```
 var travel
 document.getElementsByName("travelers").onchange=function(){          
     var travel = this.value;
 };
```

Comment: this almost work, I think, but it returns the value as "undefined"

Comment: @Freshman: check my edited answer , you need to add id attribute for select element

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value of travelers, you only have to write:

```
var travelers = document.getElementsByName("travelers").value;
```